# Plus sign in Base64.encode64 output?

Tags: python, ruby

I am using Base64.encode64 to create a hash from HMAC used in an API request (an API that I did not develop). The generated hashes *sometimes* included a "+". The requests that included the "+" fail. Requests without succeed.

The same kind of script in Python, for example, never has a "+" in the Base64 encoded hash.

Below are the two snippets. Again, the Python never has a "+", the Ruby sometimes does.

Any ideas what is going on? How can I keep Ruby's base64 encoding from using "+" characters?

**Ruby:**

```
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', hmackey, request_string)
signature = URI::encode(Base64.encode64(hmac))
```

**Python:**

```
hmac = hmac.new(self.hmackey, urltosign, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac)
```

Comment: + is a valid char in base64.  Are these equivalent?  I don't see the equivalent of your `URI::encode` step in the python, which will change all spaces to +'s also (post-base64)

Answer (score 16):

Python uses the [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html) for the [base64](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) conversion. Other languages like Ruby, Java(Possibly [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)) they may be using different RFC for the conversion. So you may find few are using `/` and few are using `+` on their encoded string.

So if you then you need to match with them, just replace the characters with equivalent one after the encoding.

Answer (score 9):

To add to @Sabuj Hassan's great answer.

In Ruby you can do `Base64.urlsafe_encode64` to comply to RFC 4648, which seems to be more universally useful.

From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64)

> Returns the Base64-encoded version of bin. This method complies with “Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet'' in RFC 4648. The alphabet uses '-' instead of '+' and '_' instead of '/'.